# Is state pattern a good solution for implementing UI changes for Landscape and Portrait modes?

Tags: design-patterns, mvc, objective-c

For our iOS app, a lot of complicated UI logic depends on the interface orientation of the ViewController. This conditional logic is present in a lot of places.

Can it be segregated into different states in form of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIViewController` is capable of handling this directly.

Let's assume most of your views' frames are being set at the same time (in your ViewController), Move all the frame setting code **into one method**.

```
-(void)setAllFrames;
```

This method will set each subview's frame according to the current interface orientation, so it will contain the logic to determine what each frame should be based on orientation.  So when the view first loads you call `[self setAllFrames];` and all the frames will be adjusted properly according to the interface orientation.

Now when the interface orientation changes, just call that method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can utilize the [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) to separate out each UI widget's layout logic into distinct classes depending on orientation.  But realize that this potentially triples the class count for your UI widgets, and forces many to be re-created each time orientation changes.

If you go forth with said pattern, make sure that you have each `Widget` defined properly, and then have distinct `landscapeWidget` and `portaitWidget` objects that inherit from the `widget`.  (Rather than placing non-layout code in both, which would be [copy and paste programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming).)

---

Of course, realize that you will eventually need to adjust the UI again, when Apple releases an iOS DVR or an iOS watch.  You may be better off defining a `layoutManager` that organizes your UI, and having all of the layout logic in there, rather than having the individual UI elements have distinct classes.  Tell the individual widget elements how much X and Y they have, and don't make them worry about the entire screen.